# convert array of object to array of integer in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

So I want to convert in ruby

```rb
[{:user_id => 4}, {:user_id => 22}, {:user_id=>51}, {:user_id=>52}]
```

to

```
[4, 22, 51, 52]
```

Is there way of convert this?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just fixed a wrong tag via “edit tags”. I wasn’t actually editing the question’s content.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, I know. My question was rhetorical.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, let's use [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to transform each item in something else

```
array.map { |item| item[:user_id] }
 => [4, 22, 51, 52]
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as possible: `array.flat_map(&:values)`

Comment: Good answer, mainly because of its flexibility and generality. For example, this works if the name of the common key in the array of single-key hashes were unknown or changed in future.